# Jenkins does not fail when the python script raise an exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins, cmd

I have a Jenkins scrip

```
pipeline
{
    agent any
    stages
    {
        stage ('Init')
        {
            steps
            {
                sh 'cmd /C "C:\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe" submodule update --init --recursive --depth=1'
            }
        }
        stage ('Build')
        {
            environment {
                PATH = "C:\\cygwin64\\bin;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\Scripts\\;C:\\Program Files\\Python310"
            }
            steps
            {
                bat 'cmd /C module release || exit /b'
            }
        }
}
```

My problem is that it always passes even though the module script fails due to raise of an exception inside my python script. If the exception is raised in python, I want the Jenkins fail too.

**Note**: I will not touch the python script to return an exit code. I want to keep the python code as it is and fix it from the Jenkins side.

How can I fix this?

module.bat

```
@echo off
set -e
python submodules/package-tools/module.py %*
```

Inside the module.py,

```
...
raise Exception('Error')
```

**[Update]**

Tried with these variations too and still have the same problem:

```
bat 'call module release'
bat 'call module release || exit /b'
bat 'module release || exit /b'
bat 'python submodules/package-tools/module.py release'
```

Also when I write:

```
bat 'python submodules/package-tools/module.py release & echo %errorlevel%'
```

Jenkins understand my command as:

```
python submodules/package-tools/module.py release   & echo 0
```

If I run the same command in a cmd in the Jenkins sever manually, what I observe as error code is `9009`. But, it seems Jenkins does not care about it and yet approves the stage.

**[Update]**

Sorry my python code had a problem. It was calling another python code via `os.system(...)` and fixed it by replacing via

```
rc = os.system('python ... .py ' + args)

if rc:
    sys.exit(n)
```

Then Jenkins

```
bat 'module release'
```

is sufficient.